# How do I solve problem with links not working on mobile with woocommerce sidebar on?

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, sidebar

I’m building this website for a client and everything went fine until I add a woocommerce sidebar widget on my shop and products page. Since I’ve done that, product links are not clickable on mobile.

I tried to deactivate some plugins but nothing worked. Mobile version works fine without sidebar, and doesn’t work at all with it.

Can anyone please help me? I’m loosing my mind already…

Theme I’m using is Insomnia
https://themeforest.net/item/insomnia-beautiful-and-modern-creative-wordpress-theme/16256975?gclid=CjwKCAjwp-X0BRAFEiwAheRuiyVZe2FxLFL9bCVPf7qCjQX9CG715ewHddt3B44EBubBcEPaxSH6zhoCUbAQAvD_BwE

Thanks in advance

The page I need help with: https://fiordilatte.pt/index.php/loja/

Comment: Add display: none; via a CSS media query (less then 768px) for .col-lg-3 This solves the problem

Answer (score 0):

What's happening here is that the sidebar is overlapping the main content on mobile view. That's why the links are not clickable - you are trying to click on an invisible element positioned on top of the links.

The reason is that in spite of you using the grid class .col-sm-12 on .sidebar-right, it is also set to float:left which will take it out of normal flow. When you then use .col-sm-12 on the element after, it thinks it got the whole width to itself - and that is also why it's not wrapping correctly.

An easy solution, but not a very elegant one, is just to force the .sidebar-right on top with the z-index property. Se example below:

```
.sidebar-right {
    z-index: 999;
}
```